# PhoneGap - CSS blink animation not working

Tags: android, cordova, css-animations

I'm developing an android app in phonegap (which is already working as a webapp) and I have a problem with a CSS blink animation not working. It works ok in Android's Chrome, but it's just not working in-App. Here's the CSS code:

```
.blinkClass{
    animation-duration: 400ms;
    animation-name: blink;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation:blink 400ms infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
@keyframes blink {
    from {
        background:#EEEEEE;
        background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(200,200,200,1),rgba(200,200,200,0) 85%);
        background: -o-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(200,200,200,1),rgba(200,200,200,0) 85%);
        background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(200,200,200,1),rgba(200,200,200,0) 85%);
        background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(200,200,200,1),rgba(200,200,200,0) 85%);
    }
    to {
        background: yellow;
        background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,255,0,1),rgba(255,255,0,0) 85%);
        background: -o-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,255,0,1),rgba(255,255,0,0) 85%);
        background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,255,0,1),rgba(255,255,0,0) 85%);
        background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,255,0,1),rgba(255,255,0,0) 85%);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    from {
        background:#EEEEEE;
        background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(200,200,200,1),rgba(200,200,200,0) 85%);
        background: -o-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(200,200,200,1),rgba(200,200,200,0) 85%);
        background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(200,200,200,1),rgba(200,200,200,0) 85%);
        background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(200,200,200,1),rgba(200,200,200,0) 85%);
    }
    to {
        background: yellow;
        background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,255,0,1),rgba(255,255,0,0) 85%);
        background: -o-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,255,0,1),rgba(255,255,0,0) 85%);
        background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,255,0,1),rgba(255,255,0,0) 85%);
        background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,255,0,1),rgba(255,255,0,0) 85%);
    }
}
```

Any idea about what could be wrong?

EDIT:

It's not working with android's default browser.

EDIT2:

I found that android's default browser doesn't support complex CSS animations, only simple ones. If I do something like:

```
@-webkit-keyframes blink2 {
    from {opacity: 1.0;}
    to {opacity: 0.0;}
}
```

It works fine. The new problem is, how do I separate the `radial-gradient` into parts?

Comment: Does it work in the device's default browser (the one it came with when it shipped)?

Comment: @Likwid_T Emmm..... good point. Just checked, it's not working. :S

Comment: That's the browser cordova is using when it creates a view for you, look up css solutions with regards to that browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this many times using CSS. It is **extremely** important to use the -webkit- tags on css components.

Use -webkit-background as well as standard background variables in css. This error also occurs for things such as **transform** which should be **-webkit-transform:**

Play around with it. iOS is really good for stuff like this unfortunately android isnt!

J

Comment: Well, the background works just fine without the animation, but I'll give it a try for sure ;)  Anyway, this just seem to happen with old devices.